# Remove a specific word and everything after in a Cell

Tags: vba, excel, replace, excel-2010

I'm having trouble deleting everything after and including the word **`APT`** and **`STE`** on Address column

If you look at the result blow, my vba code is deleting the word that the letters **ste** ( *2121 **STE**VENSON LN*) or **apt**.

What is best way to to remove the word APT or STE and everything after that?

Below is my code,

```
Option Explicit
Sub Remove()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    With Sht.Range("E:E")
        .Replace "APT*", "", xlPart
        .Replace "STE*", "", xlPart
    End With

End Sub
```

My Data

```
+-------+-----+-----+----------+----------------------------------+-------+------+-----+
| Route | Pcs | Wgt | Location |             Address              | Suite | City | Zip |
+-------+-----+-----+----------+----------------------------------+-------+------+-----+
| SD-26 |   1 |   3 |          | 5555 SOUTHWESTERN BLVD           |       |      |     |
| SD-26 |   1 |   7 |          | 6666 EASTERN AVE APT 100         |       |      |     |
| SD-05 |   1 |   1 |          | 161112 HOMESTEAD ST              |       |      |     |
| SD-05 |   2 |   8 |          | 2221 STEVENSON LN                |       |      |     |
| SD-04 |   1 |   8 |          | 4040 OLD DENTON RD APT 2104      |       |      |     |
| SD-04 |   1 |   3 |          | 15811 E FRANKFORD RD APT 1507    |       |      |     |
| SD-04 |   1 |   1 |          | 835 WESTMINSTER DR               |       |      |     |
| SD-03 |   1 |   5 |          | 9001 LAKESIDE CIR APT 5203       |       |      |     |
| SD-03 |   1 |   3 |          | 8880 UNION STATION PKWY APT 2104 |       |      |     |
| SD-03 |   1 |   1 |          | 420 E MAIN ST STE E              |       |      |     |
+-------+-----+-----+----------+----------------------------------+-------+------+-----+
```

Result

```
+-------+-----+-----+----------+--------------------------+-------+------+-----+
| Route | Pcs | Wgt | Location |         Address          | Suite | City | Zip |
+-------+-----+-----+----------+--------------------------+-------+------+-----+
| SD-26 |   1 |   3 |          | 5555 SOUTHWE             |       |      |     |
| SD-26 |   1 |   7 |          | 6666 EA                  |       |      |     |
| SD-05 |   1 |   1 |          | 161112 HOME              |       |      |     |
| SD-05 |   2 |   8 |          | 2221                     |       |      |     |
| SD-04 |   1 |   8 |          | 4040 OLD DENTON RD       |       |      |     |
| SD-04 |   1 |   3 |          | 15811 E FRANKFORD RD     |       |      |     |
| SD-04 |   1 |   1 |          | 835 WESTMIN              |       |      |     |
| SD-03 |   1 |   5 |          | 9001 LAKESIDE CIR        |       |      |     |
| SD-03 |   1 |   3 |          | 8880 UNION STATION PKWY  |       |      |     |
| SD-03 |   1 |   1 |          | 420 E MAIN ST            |       |      |     |
+-------+-----+-----+----------+--------------------------+-------+------+-----+
```

Comment: i think wildcard only works on .FIND but not .REPLACE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me you can just include a space before and after APT/STE but before the wildcard character.

```
Sub RemoveAptSte()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    With Sht.Range("E:E")
        .Replace " APT *", vbNullString, xlPart
        .Replace " STE *", vbNullString, xlPart
    End With

End Sub
```

That should remove just about any false positive from consideration.

[image: apt_ste]

Comment: lol - I did add space but it was after the wildcard `" APT* "` ++1